# Regular Expressions: Capture only the matching group to replace whole text

Tags: regex

This is my first couple of days, trying regular expressions and I use Notepad++

I need help, I have this data (confidential stuff redacted), which I want to extract and print (like web crawling, this is a HTML code from drop down). I need to extract quoted string after data-value" replacing rest of the stuff.

Regular Expressions to match: \bdata-value="(\w+)"+ (The data I want is in the captured group and I want to print only that information)

**Test Sample:**

```
<div class="selectize-dropdown form-control multi plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 238px; top: 34px; left: 0px;" xpath="1"><div class="selectize-dropdown-content"><div data-value="TESTSTRING" data-selectable="" class="option">TEST data 1?</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGG" data-selectable="" class="Te`enter code here`st 2">Data Type</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">Data</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">All Clear</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">Amount Involved</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">Trigger Data</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGGGGG"
```

**Output expected is**
TESTSTRING
TESTSTRINGG
TESTSTRINGGG
TESTSTRINGGGG
TESTSTRINGGGGG
TESTSTRINGGGGGG
TESTSTRINGGGGGGG

** I tried the following **

1. ^. \bdata-value="([^\w+])"+  - From he start select every thing except captured bracket and replace with none - Did not work
2. ^.+ (?=\bdata-value="(^[\w+])"+).+ Here I tried to use Lookahead After the Match:I am trying to capture every thing until the group "data-value" capture that in a group and exclude actual output

   3. Similarly tried other ways, none are successful.

In my test output please note that if i type $, it does not show end of line, it is at end of file and I tried to create new lines by adding newline characters at the end of the group. But that did not help me much. Please can you help me with possible solutions and bit of explanations so that I can learn, thanks a ton.

Comment: Your output appears to have nothing to do with the input.  Can you explain this?

Comment: Sorry, I realised my test input is truncated and trying to explore how to edit it

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have edited the question, I posted the HTML with quotes so you can see the test data now. please can you confirm

Comment: Notepad++ is really not the best tool to be using here.  Can you use some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is not the best tool here, and if you want to use regex you should be using a tool which can iterate and match repeatedly.  For example, in Python we can try:

```
s = """<div class="selectize-dropdown form-control multi plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 238px; top: 34px; left: 0px;" xpath="1"><div class="selectize-dropdown-content"><div data-value="TESTSTRING" data-selectable="" class="option">TEST data 1?</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGG" data-selectable="" class="Te`enter code here`st 2">Data Type</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">Data</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">All Clear</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">Amount Involved</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGGGG" data-selectable="" class="option">Trigger Data</div><div data-value="TESTSTRINGGGGGGG"""
matches = re.findall(r'\bdata-value="(.*?)"', s)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['TESTSTRING', 'TESTSTRINGG', 'TESTSTRINGGG', 'TESTSTRINGGGG', 'TESTSTRINGGGGG', 'TESTSTRINGGGGGG']
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I downloaded pycharm and tested your code and also with my actual data, works like charm. Pardon my ignorance, its more than decade i coded,  how easy to print in a file, with new line. So cannot use notepad++ at all?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking.  There probably is a way to do this from Notepad++, but as I mentioned NPP is not the best tool here.  You would be better off using a good regex API from a programming language.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I will try it out, actually I was curious if I can redirect the console output to file. Thanks a ton really.

Comment: There are specific programs and librairies for selecting nodes from a xml file, v.gr. `xpath -e //div/@data-value file.xml`. An html file can easily be converterted into a compliant xml file.